# Images animation with completion block?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Using Swift ,  I animate multiple images with :

```
    cp.animationImages = images
    cp.animationDuration = TimeInterval(speed)
    cp.animationRepeatCount=count
    cp.startAnimating()
```

I use all sorts of delays to wait between them, but when I need to run a sequence of animations, I would like to have a delegate so each call will be finished with a certain tag, so I can then decide what to do.
I could not find how to use a block/delegate in Swift for this animation.

Comment: What is cp? Is it an image?

Comment: Sorry! Its a UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

`UIImageView` does not support animation completion handlers, but there are extensions available:

https://github.com/gurmundi7/UIImageView-AnimationCompletionBlock